# Generate JsonSchema from liquid Object

Tags: liquid-xml

It is my first time to use liquid.

I generate class from xsd for my c# application.

I need to dynamically generate Jsonschema  from liquid c# object.

someone can help please ?

I try to generate json schema dynamically with liquid c# object

Answer (score 1):

Liquid XML Objects support [round-trip of XML to JSON](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-data-binder/using-json-with-liquid-xml-objects), but you cannot dynamically create a JSON schema from the objects.

You can [Infer a JSON Schema from a JSON Document](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/infer-json-schema), but this would be a manual task from within Liquid Studio.

You can also Convert an XSD to a JSON Schema, but again this would be a manual task within Liquid Studio.